# How to configure coloring of the file names in MC?

Tags: midnight-commander

Is it possible to configure the Midnight Commander (Ubuntu 10.10) to show certain file and directory names differently, e.g. all hidden (starting with a period) using grey color?

Answer (score 3):

Under **Options -> Panel Options** select **File highlight -> File types**.

[image: Midnight Commander Panel options screenshot]

See `man mc` in the Colors section for ways to choose particular colors by adding entries in your `~/.config/mc/ini` file. Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a keyword for hidden files.

Comment: Not only that there is no keyword for hidden files, I even have no success in changing an existing regex (e.g. for temp files) to match files/directories starting with a period.

Comment: How exactly can entries be added to `~/.config/mc/ini`? I managed to add them to ~/.config/mc/[filehighlight.ini](https://github.com/MidnightCommander/mc/blob/master/misc/filehighlight.ini), but then you have to copy/paste there the default ones. For syntax highlight, there's `~/.config/mc/mcedit/Syntax`.

Comment: `M+.` to toggle hidden files. Note that `Meta` key might be `Esc`, so also try `Esc` `.`